# Python: Compare regex pattern in one text file against line in another

Tags: python, regex

This works in smaller text files, but not on larger. (100,000 lines) 
How can I optimize for large text files? 
For line in fileA if regexPattern == line in fileB write (entire)line in fileA to fileC.

```
import re

with open('fileC.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('fileA.txt', 'rU') as infile1:
        for line1 in infile1:
            y = re.findall(r'^.+,.+,(.+\.[a-z]+$)', line1)
                with open('fileB.txt', 'rU') as infile2:
                    for line2 in infile2:
                        if line2.strip() == y[0]:
                            outfile.write(line1)
```

Comment: Ok.But what is the question?

Comment: For every line in file A you're looping through *every* line in file B. If there are 100,000 lines in A and 100,000 lines in B, you're doing ten billion operations. Which is going to take a while...

Comment: Thank you. Added a question.

Comment: One option is to read fileB and hash every single lines with md5 and store all of them in memory, then extract the content from fileA and compare the hash with the hash from fileB. If they are the same, then it is extremely likely that they have the same content.

Comment: I would suggest that when you ask a question, provide a *small* example of example input data and desired output data.

Comment: Lines in fileA would look like: date,title,url  and lines in fileB: url. The regex pattern matches the url in fileA, and when it finds a match in fileB it writes the entire line from fileA to fileC.

Answer (score 0):

The most immediate optimization is to read `fileB.txt` only once into a string buffer, then apply the test against the matched expression to that string buffer. You are currently opening and reading that file once for each line of `fileA.txt`.

It seems that your regex picks up whole lines that match a pattern, i.e. it starts with `^` and ends with `$`. In this case, a more complete solution would be to load both `fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt` into arrays using `readlines()`, sort those arrays, then take a single pass through both files with two counters, e.g.:

```
# Details regarding the treatment of duplicate lines are ignored
# for clarity of exposition.
rai = sorted([7,6,1,9,11,6])
raj = sorted([4,6,11,7])
i, j = 0, 0
while i < len(rai) and j < len(raj):
    if   rai[i] < raj[j]: i += 1
    elif rai[i] > raj[j]: j += 1
    else:
        # I used mod in lieu of testing for your regex
        # since you didnt supply data
        if mod(rai[i],2): print rai[i]
        i, j = i + 1, j + 1
```

Comment: Thank you. The regex matches a pattern within an entire line in fileA. When that pattern is matched in fileB the desired outcome is to write the entire line from fileA (not just the pattern that was matched).

Comment: No problem. To keep track of the entire line from `fileA`, you can update the code above to make `rai` an array of matches. Depending on duplicates, you may also need a hash from the match to the line matched. You still want to sort `fileB` to remove an O(n^2) operation.